# mysql Query make Db Storage full

Tags: mysql

I am having issue with mysql query.

```
SELECT Count(*) AS aggregate
FROM   (SELECT Group_concat(gateways.public_name) AS client_gateways,
           `clients`.`id`,
           `clients`.`name`,
           `clients`.`status`,
           `clients`.`api_key`,
           `clients`.`user_name`,
           `clients`.`psp_id`,
           `clients`.`suspend`,
           `clients`.`secret_key`,
           `clients`.`created_at`,
           `companies`.`name`                 AS `company_name`,
           `mid_groups_mid`.`mid_id`,
           `mid_groups_mid`.`mid_group_id`,
           `mid_groups`.`id`                  AS `group_id`,
           `mid_groups`.`user_id`,
           `mids`.`mid_group_id`              AS `id_of_mid`
    FROM   `clients`
           LEFT JOIN `client_site_gateways`
                  ON `clients`.`id` = `client_site_gateways`.`client_id`
           LEFT JOIN `gateways`
                  ON `client_site_gateways`.`gateway_id` = `gateways`.`id`
           LEFT JOIN `client_broker`
                  ON `client_broker`.`client_id` = `clients`.`id`
           LEFT JOIN `mid_groups`
                  ON `mid_groups`.`user_id` = `clients`.`psp_id`
           LEFT JOIN `mid_groups_mid`
                  ON `mid_groups_mid`.`mid_group_id` = `mid_groups`.`id`
           LEFT JOIN `mids`
                  ON `mids`.`mid_group_id` = `mid_groups_mid`.`mid_group_id`
           INNER JOIN `companies`
                   ON `companies`.`id` = `clients`.`company_id`
    WHERE  `is_corp` = 0
           AND `clients`.`suspend` = '0'
           AND ( `clients`.`company_id` = 1 )
           AND `clients`.`deleted_at` IS NULL
    
    GROUP  BY `clients`.`id`,
              `clients`.`name`,
              `clients`.`status`,
              `clients`.`api_key`,
              `clients`.`suspend`,
              `clients`.`secret_key`,
              `clients`.`created_at`,
              `companies`.`name`,
              `clients`.`user_name`,
              `clients`.`psp_id`,
              `mid_groups_mid`.`mid_id`,
              `mid_groups_mid`.`mid_group_id`,
              `mid_groups`.`id`,
              `mid_groups`.`user_id`,
              `mids`.`mid_group_id`) count_row_table
```

all table have few hundreds records. here is explain query result

```
+------+-------------+----------------------+--------+-------------------------------------+-------------------------------------+---------+----------------------------------------------+------------+-------------------------------------------------+
| id   | select_type | table                | type   | possible_keys                       | key                                 | key_len | ref                                          | rows       | Extra                                           |
+------+-------------+----------------------+--------+-------------------------------------+-------------------------------------+---------+----------------------------------------------+------------+-------------------------------------------------+
|    1 | PRIMARY     | <derived2>           | ALL    | NULL                                | NULL                                | NULL    | NULL                                         | 2849642280 |                                                 |
|    2 | DERIVED     | companies            | const  | PRIMARY                             | PRIMARY                             | 4       | const                                        |          1 | Using temporary; Using filesort                 |
|    2 | DERIVED     | clients              | ref    | clients_company_id_foreign          | clients_company_id_foreign          | 4       | const                                        |        543 | Using where                                     |
|    2 | DERIVED     | client_site_gateways | ref    | client_id                           | client_id                           | 4       | knox_staging.clients.id                      |          5 |                                                 |
|    2 | DERIVED     | gateways             | eq_ref | PRIMARY                             | PRIMARY                             | 4       | knox_staging.client_site_gateways.gateway_id |          1 | Using where                                     |
|    2 | DERIVED     | client_broker        | ALL    | NULL                                | NULL                                | NULL    | NULL                                         |          6 | Using where; Using join buffer (flat, BNL join) |
|    2 | DERIVED     | mid_groups           | ref    | mid_groups_user_id_foreign          | mid_groups_user_id_foreign          | 4       | knox_staging.clients.psp_id                  |          1 | Using where; Using index                        |
|    2 | DERIVED     | mid_groups_mid       | ref    | mid_groups_mid_mid_group_id_foreign | mid_groups_mid_mid_group_id_foreign | 8       | knox_staging.mid_groups.id                   |        433 | Using where                                     |
|    2 | DERIVED     | mids                 | ref    | mids_mid_group_id_foreign           | mids_mid_group_id_foreign           | 9       | knox_staging.mid_groups_mid.mid_group_id     |        404 | Using where; Using index                        |
+------+-------------+----------------------+--------+-------------------------------------+-------------------------------------+---------+----------------------------------------------+------------+-------------------------------------------------+
```

in explain results what is causing to have 2849642280 row. while tables have only few hundreds records. all tables have proper indexing.
what i am thinking causing storage full is tmp table with above records. i tried to scale storage upto 60GB database size is few MBs. all storage filled up as soon as i run above query. i am not sure what causing left join to filter 2849642280 rows

Answer (score 0):

The problem is probably the "aggregate."  If the only thing you need is the count of records, you should write a *new* query which gets that count.

Comment: ok. i tried without subquery and it seems showing correct records. but causing sub query to have that issue ?